# How to implement Git tag and merge on release?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, git-tag

The final stage of our release pipeline is a manual stage used to confirm the deployed release got its final acceptance. Among the tasks we would like to run in this stage:

- Tag the *develop* branch with the release label. Say "1.2.3".
- Merge the *develop* branch into the *master* branch.

(We're using Azure Git repositories)

Although it looks like the right moment to make these changes in Git, I'm not quite certain this is the intended usage of Azure release pipelines. I confess being a bit new to Azure pipelines and there seem to be no evident pipeline task for doing such changes.

However, I believe this kind of post-release SCM changes is quite common.

My question is therefore: Where and how is the proper way to apply those SCM changes in Azure Devops ?

EDIT: I could make it work to use a command line task to run git commands. Config was passed by means of a variable group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do the regular git commands in a Command Line script (first , clone the repo (or add it as an artifact), then tag/merge).

Or install the [Tag Git on Release](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liquorichris.tag-git-release) & [Git Merge](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dtzar.git-merge) extensions and use them.

Comment: Is there some kind of system account to clone the repository ? I'm having the issue tags added in the build pipeline can not be removed in a release pipeline. But it can remove its own tags.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand... what is the issue?

Comment: Fixed ! It was a permission missing (forcePush). However I had to put it for all repositories for it work.